# how to select Dc Motor

Tags: motor, dc-motor, brushless-dc-motor

I have air conditioning application where i want to run blower @ 1500 rpm. Motor is rated for 48-56v DC. The operation of motor is continuous mode. Let me know calculation involved here

1. Minimum amount of noise
2. heat dissipation should be less
3. how torque, wattage of motor is calculated?
4. How to make the load uniformly loaded

The fans are mounted on either end of shaft of motor. Shaft dia 0.5" . Where fan radius is 20cm & 450Gm. There two fans which are mounted on either side.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fl6Mt6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
[how motor connected](http://www.searspartsdirect.com/partsdirect/part-model/whirlpool-parts/air-conditioner-parts/Model-ACM062XH0/1198/0904032/o2028376/00001)

Comment: Do you mean AC power conditioning application, or an air conditioning application? This sounds like a blower design problem, not an electrical problem. You can find motor ratings for RPM, voltage, current, wattage, and torque in the motor datasheet.

Comment: You also need to know the torque required to run each fan at 1500rpm.  And what does 450Gm mean?

Comment: for your information link attached

Comment: @user6972 that is what i am asking above how to calculate torque & power relevant to [link](weight.http://www.searspartsdirect.com/partsdirect/part-model/whirlpool-parts/air-conditioner-parts/Model-ACM062XH0/1198/0904032/o2028376/00001) here how connection look like

Comment: @AMPS you have to know the dynamics of the fan you're using to compute the torque at 1500rpm, or have equipment to measure it.  Since it appears you are just trying to replace a broken motor, why don't you get the voltage/power ratings off the broken one and then get a replacement with the same ratings?

Answer (score 2):

There are many HVAC sites that will give you air movement data, but using a standard formula based on max acceleration principles you'll get an approximate idea:

Power ~~~ = 0.5 x Density x Area x V^3

**In 'metric' / ISO units**:

Density = 1.2 kg/m^3 at sea level and 25C
V = Velocity at exit in m/s
A = Area of exit in m^2
Power in Watts

---

IF you know torque them

Power ~= torque x RPM

Torque in kg.m
Power in Watts

This is a "bodge" formula whose constants happen to come out to within about 1% when ISO units are used. .

ie 2 x Pi x g ~~~= 60 (where there are 60 RPM in an RPS)

---

Fans produce ~~~ equal "load" when they produce equal power using above formula.

Or A x V^3 is equal in each case.

This fails with too much compressibility, which is not liable to be a major issue in most fan and ventilation cases. If this is for eg the intake fans in a jet engine you may perhaps need better precision of calculation :-).